# Search filter for angular2 + ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to implement search functionalities with ionic2 + angular2. In previous version I used [This Filter Example](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_filters_input)
but in newer version this is not working.

How it is work with angular2 + ionic2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Searchbar component](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#searchbar). Please take a look at this [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/36zHb2?p=preview).

It's pretty easy to use, first in your `Component` make sure to have a list of items to show in the view.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular/index';

@Component({
     templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor() {
    this.initializeItems();
  }

  initializeItems() {
    this.items = [
      'Amsterdam',
      'Bogota',
      'Buenos Aires',
      'Dhaka'
    ];
  }

  getItems(ev) {
    // Reset items back to all of the items
    this.initializeItems();

    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
        return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Just like you can see in that code, the magic is being done in these lines of code:

```
// if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
if (val && val.trim() != '') {
  this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
    return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
  })
}
```

So everytime you type something, we filter the items that contains the what you've typed in the search bar. Then add this code in your view:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar primary>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic 2
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{ item }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Please notice that we're binding the `ionInput` event from the `ion-searchbar` element to the `getItems` method by doing:

```
(ionInput)="getItems($event)
```